# release build variable corruption when using ne10 math library assembly function

Tags: eclipse, c++11, embedded-linux, neon

has anyone experience the following issue?

```
A stack variable getting changed/corrupted after calling ne10 assembly function such as ne10_len_vec2f_neon?
e.g
float gain = 8.0;
ne10_len_vec2f_neon(src, dst, len);

after the call to ne10_len_vec2f_neon, the value of gain changes as its memory is getting corrupted.

1.  Note this only happens when the project is compiled in release build but not debug build.
2.  Does Ne10 assembly functions preserve registers?
3.  Replacing the assembly function call to c equivalent such as ne10_len_vec2f_c and both release and debug build seem to work OK.
```

thanks for any help on this.  Not sure if there's an inherent issue within the program or it is really the call to ne10_len_vec2f_neon causing the corruption with release build.enter code here

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick rummage through the master NEON code here:

- https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/blob/master/modules/math/NE10_len.neon.s

... and it doesn't really touch address-based stack at all, so not sure it's a stack problem in memory.

However based on what I remember of the NEON procedure call standard `q4-q7` (alias `d8-d15` or `s16-s31`) should be preserved by the callee, and as far as I can tell that code is clobbering `q4-6` without the necessary save/restore, so it does indeed look like it's clobbering the stack in registers.

In the failed case do you know if `gain` is still stored in FPU registers, and if yes which ones? If it's stored in any of `s16/17/18/19` then this looks like the problem. It also seems plausible that a compiler would choose to use `s16` upwards for things it needs to keep across a function call, as it avoids the need to touch in-RAM stack memory.

In terms of a fix, if you perform the following replacements:

- `s/q4/q8/`
- `s/q5/q9/`
- `s/q6/q10/`

in that file, then I think it should work; no means to test here, but those higher register blocks are not callee saved.

Comment: I've raised an issue in the Ne10 github: https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/issues/138

Comment: Hi thanks for the followup on this.  I was suspecting about q4-q7 not getting preserved but wasn't entirely sure since the debug build seemed to work OK.  I was having a hard time stepping into the disassembly so not sure about checking the gain variable.  I've actually simplified my question by making gain a local variable when in fact it's actually a function parameter totally unrelated to the ne10_len_vec2f_neon call.

Comment: In my experience in debug builds compilers tend to stack to RAM more often than not, which would make this issue vanish.

Comment: Not sure if you saw the update - but I'd added some info on a plausible fix to my answer - just swap the use of q4-6 with q8-10 and that should work (if this is indeed the problem, anyway).

Comment: Yes I intend to verify with your suggestion when get a chance.